# Testing Rails model in Spec, how to create efficient examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test my models in Rails using Rspec and FactoryBot. I am using `let!`:

```
let!(:account1) { create(:account, :year) }
let!(:account2) { create(:account, :three_months) }
let!(:account3) { create(:account, :month) }
let!(:account4) { create(:account, :day) }
```

I'm testing whether my scopes are returning the correct array of records. My assumption is that there should also be some "bad data", to test if the scope isn't returning stuff it shouldn't. For instance:

```
  describe ".seen_last_two_months" do
    subject { Account.seen_last_two_months.to_a }
    it { is_expected.to eq([account3, account4]) }
  end
```

It seems that, when the amount of tests grow, the speed drops significantly. It seems that each test that invokes `let!` hits the database, creating a new record.

1. Is the way I'm setting up my tests correct, so should I also test for records that are not expected to be returned by the query?
2. Is there a way to invoke the creation of the records only once?

Comment: _"My assumption here, is that there should also be some "bad data", to test if the scope isn't returning stuff it shouldn't."_ - i totally agree with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is the way I'm setting up my tests correct, so should I also test for records that are not expected to be returned by the query?

Yes, simply you should.

> 2. Is there a way to invoke the creation of the records only once?

Yes, you need these records to be created to test a particular scope. So, they should be called only for that particular test. You can move them to the scope-test related `describe` block and then they won't be invoked for other tests.

```
# Keep this one without `!`, so it will be called (in other tests), if and when needed
let(:account1) { create(:account, :year) }

describe ".seen_last_two_months" do
  let!(:account1) { create(:account, :year) }
  let!(:account2) { create(:account, :three_months) }
  let!(:account3) { create(:account, :month) }
  let!(:account4) { create(:account, :day) }
  subject { Account.seen_last_two_months.to_a }
  it { is_expected.to eq([account3, account4]) }
end
```

**Update**

If you want to create records only once for all the tests, use `before(:all)` instead. It looks like calling `let` defined variables inside `before(:all)` block is a bad idea, use instance variables instead:

```
before(:all) do
  @account1 = create(:account, :year)
  @account2 = create(:account, :three_months)
  @account3 = create(:account, :month)
  @account4 = create(:account, :day)
end

describe ".seen_last_two_months" do
  subject { Account.seen_last_two_months.to_a }
  it { is_expected.to eq([@account3, @account4]) }
end
```

Replace all occurrences of `account*` with `@account*` in your tests.

Remember, the changes made by any test in an object will also reflect in the next tests.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I need accounts2,3,4 also in the other tests. Just hoped I could work with a situation in which I can write the database only once, and run multiple tests on those records.

Comment: Ah, nice! That was what I was looking for.

Comment: This seems to be giving errors by the way. `let declaration `account1` accessed in a `before(:context)` hook at:`, any ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer to use instance variables. Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create all accounts once and test all your scopes on them. Just move all under `it` block, something like this:

```
context "scopes" do
  it 'selects accounts correctly' do
    let!(:account1) { create(:account, :year) }
    let!(:account2) { create(:account, :three_months) }
    let!(:account3) { create(:account, :month) }
    let!(:account4) { create(:account, :day) }

    expect(Account.seen_last_two_months.to_a).to eq([account3, account4])
    expect(Account.another_scope.to_a).to eq([account1, account2])
    expect(Account.one_more_scope.to_a).to eq([account2])
  end
end
```

But this kind of specs are more difficult to maintain, you need to specify many different attributes in your instances to check all scopes. I use this way only for similar scopes, for example scopes by status ('active', 'inactive', 'archived').

btw: it is always a good idea to give more descriptive names, like

```
let!(:year_ago) { create(:account, :year) }
```